# GitLab: How do I make a specific user the owner of a specific project in a namespace?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a namespace called **games** with many projects in it. How do I make a specific user the owner of a specific project in the **games** namespace?

We are using GitLab CE 8.12.7

Answer (score 0):

you can access the project members url of your project:

```
https//mygitlab.com/games/specific_project/project_members
```

There, you can manage the access level for each users, including the level "Owner". Click on the "`Manage group members`" button.

[image: owner]